# Invalid address

Tags: contract-development, truffle, addresses, ganache, testing

I deployed my contract in ganache. When I was started to call a function with two arguments I started getting an error. I used an address from ganache.

```
Error: invalid address (arg="user", coderType="address", value=##)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:83
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  reason: 'invalid address',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  arg: 'user',
  coderType: 'address',
  value: ##,
```

Comment: What does the code do? What are the parameter values?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to execute one of my smart contracts function with a wrong address and it gave me the following error in remix-

> Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid address (arg="",
> coderType="address",
> value="0x5398EC4AE74D9a98dD5318026A6de997f6E19FB", version=4.0.45)

I am not very sure - why the **Value** in your case is - **##** *(don't think that's a correct Hash)* when the function might be accepting an address. Also,  double check on any pre-condition to the function call - which could be checking if the address exists or not.